# Continue Task after all tasks finish

Tags: c#, android, .net-4.0, android-asynctask, task

In some class I want to load 2 collection asynchronously with Task and stop busyindicator

I try Something like this

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
WaitingIndicatorViewModel.IsBusy = true;
var loadData1 = new Task<ObservableCollection<Data1>>(GetData1FromService).ContinueWith(t => Data1Collection = t.Result, uiScheduler);
var loadData2 = new Task<ObservableCollection<Data2>>(GetData2FromService).ContinueWith(t => Data2Collection = t.Result, uiScheduler);

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
                loadData1.Start();//<--Exception here           
                loadData2.Start();
                Task.WaitAll(loadData1, loadData2);
        })
.ContinueWith(o => WaitingIndicatorViewModel.IsBusy = false, uiScheduler);
```

But this throw an exception `InvalidOperationException:Start may not be called on a continuation task.`

Why this doesn't work, and how can I run continue task after finishing both tasks, without blocking current thread?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Do the tasks loadData1 and loadData2 have any relevance here?

Comment: No @Tudor, this is whole code I have, GetData1FromService and GetData2FromService methods just return data without any task

Comment: How are loadChildAreasTask and loadAreaTypesTask defined?

Comment: Where do loadChildAreasTask and loadAreaTypesTask come from?

Comment: Should `loadData1` be `loadChildAreasTask`?  Is this a typo?

Comment: no @ChrisShain, shouldn't, Marc is right, ContinueWith is another task, which couldn't be started

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var loadData1 = new Task<ObservableCollection<Data1>>(GetData1FromService)
               .ContinueWith(t => Data1Collection = t.Result, uiScheduler);
```

I think what you mean is:

```
var loadData1 = new Task<ObservableCollection<Data1>>(GetData1FromService);
loadData1.ContinueWith(t => Data1Collection = t.Result, uiScheduler);
```

Now you can (later) call:

```
loadData1.Start();
```

The difference is that we are assigning `loadData1` to the ***outermost*** task. In your original code, you are assigning `loadData1` the result of `ContinueWith`, which is something else (a second task, so that you can wait or continue from the **second** task).

Note: if you want to wait for the inner task, you should capture the result of the `ContinueWith` call into a new variable, and wait on *that*.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Marc! you are completely right!! I change call to Task.Factory.Start which starts first task automatically, and it works excellent